# Biztalk mapping looping

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I have an input message with three segments like this

```
<DDT>
 <NumeroDDT>PS-1713445</NumeroDDT> 
 <Date>2017-10-19</Date> 
 <NumeroLinea>2</NumeroLinea> 
</DDT>
```

But I want to map the lines (NumeroLinea) based on the value in it.
So with value 2 like here it should become

```
<DDT>
 <NumeroDDT>PS-1713445</NumeroDDT> 
 <Date>2017-10-19</Date> 
 <NumeroLinea>1</NumeroLinea>
 <NumeroLinea>2</NumeroLinea> 
</DDT>
```

A sort of line counter.

I have done so with an inline xslt functoid and hard coded like..
if 1 make one line
if 2 make two lines
etc.
That would have been good enough with few lines but the problem is it can be many lines, over 300 or more so it is a bad solution and does not work.

Do you have any idea how to generate the `<NumeroLinea>` lines here based on the value from the input message?
I have also tried looping functoiods but with no luck.

Input schema and output schema is the same.

Comment: To clarify, you want the count of output NumeroLinea to equal the value in the input NumeroLinea?

Comment: Hi If the NumeroLinea  has value 3 in the input message, I want go generate three segments of NumeroLinea in the output. 
NumeroLinea 1,
NumeroLinea 2 and
NumeroLinea 3
And if it has even more in the input like 250 I want to generate 
NumeroLinea 1
NumeroLinea 2
...
NumeroLinea 250

So the input decides the number of NumeroLinea nodes to generate.

I think xslt is the only way to do this, but I don't find any good examples really.

Answer (score 0):

Found a very good solution at Seroter's blog [Splitting Delimited Values in BizTalk Maps](https://seroter.wordpress.com/2008/10/07/splitting-delimited-values-in-biztalk-maps/)

I tried it and it worked well. All I have to do is to separate my input node with a pipe and this solution works fine.

Comment: Hi Rolf. Well done on solving your problem. If you could add some more details to the answer that would be good.  An answer which only contains a link and not enough details for someone to use that answer without a link is considered low quality and they tend to get deleted.  This is because if the page that is being linked to disappears, then the answer becomes useless